# what is the programming language for SDK development for Mobile app

Tags: android, ios, mobile, sdk

I am planning to develop a SDK to be used in mobile app development. Should I develop the SDK with Kotlin for Android and Swift for iOS?

I am also thinking is there a single cross-platform language (perhaps Java) or framework which I can use to develop my SDK and then it can support both Android and iOS, is there any recommendation on the language and framework?

thanks
Paul

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's depends on which developers you are targeting and what you are trying to develop.

The majority of developers will probably use native solutions, Objective-C /Swift for iOS and Java/Kotlin for Android and the is no way of creating a single library for both unless you develop C/C++ code but this would probably be problematic at best.

There are multi-platform frameworks such as React but you will be targeting a specific set of programmers for this.

Comment: C/C++ with a small for each OS to bridge to their native languages is viable, depending on what they're doing.  If its highly algorithmic, its a good choice-  a single copy of the code is better, and C languages are highly efficient.  If its highly dependent on interacting with OS level concepts (for example, its a UI layer) its probably the wrong choice.

Comment: Thanks, you just answered exactly what I was asking. I am targeting mobile gaming developers and develop the SDK to track user retention. The SDK is not intending to support core game development, rather it will capture usage data. I have not decided but it may include some UI features e.g. in-app messaging etc. I don't think it will be a very scientific or performance oriented SDK, so the C languages may not be my choice.